# not null and is unique constraint

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2005, which system table holds the information as to whether a 
column is nullable or not, whether a index is unique or not asc or dec.

Thanks,
Jude

Answer (score 2):

- column nullability: [`sys.columns.is_nullable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx)
- index uniqueness: [`sys.indexes.is_unique`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173760.aspx)
- index key ascending/descending: [`sys.index_columns.is_descending_key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175105.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS -- gives column info
    SELECT * FROM sys.indexes --gives info for indexes